# Jenkins : Where does Jenkins store configuration files for the assigned users(ldap user)?

Tags: jenkins

I set the LDAP into Jenkins and assigned some users. Now, is anybody knows where Jenkins stores all these info? I checked in config.xml but didn't found. (It have the ldap setting but not the users list)

I logged myself out now so can't use Jenkins UI. I think I have to enable the admin again in that list.

Answer (score 2):

First, check if this [article could help](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/206598218-How-do-I-login-to-Jenkins-when-I-locked-myself-out-)

> Edit the `config.xml` file in the `JENKINS_HOME` folder and locate this line:
>
> ```
> <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
> ```

Set it to false, and restart Jenkins.

Users are, on first login, created/stored under `JENKINS_HOME/users` (see [this article for illustration](https://www.cyberark.com/threat-research-blog/tripping-the-jenkins-main-security-circuit-breaker-an-inside-look-at-two-jenkins-security-vulnerabilities/))

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins does not support LDAP and local user list together, see also [this feature request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3404). By enabling LDAP you disabled your local user configuration.